# how would i display this PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, printing

I think that i am doint something wrong in the loop, could someone please point me in the right direction? I just need to print the array.

```
<?php

   $sales["mens"]["Steven"]["May13"] = 300;
   $sales["womens"]["Jane"]["May13"] = 200;
   $sales["mens"]["Steven"]["Jun13"] = 500;
   $sales["mens"]["Steven"]["Jul13"] = 250;
   $sales["mens"]["Steven"]["Aug13"] = 375;
   $sales["mens"]["Steven"]["Sep13"] = 125;
   $sales["mens"]["John"]["Jun13"] = 100;
   $sales["mens"]["John"]["Jul13"] = 700;
   $sales["mens"]["John"]["Aug13"] = 800;
   $sales["womens"]["Jane"]["Jun13"] = 300;
   $sales["womens"]["Jane"]["Jul13"] = 400;
   $sales["womens"]["Jane"]["Aug13"] = 800;
   $sales["shoes"]["April"]["Jun13"] = 200;
   $sales["shoes"]["April"]["Jul13"] = 200;
   $sales["shoes"]["April"]["Aug13"] = 200;
   $sales["shoes"]["April"]["May13"] = 300;
   $sales["shoes"]["April"]["Sep13"] = 300;
   $sales["shoes"]["Paula"]["May13"] = 300;
   $sales["shoes"]["Paula"]["Jun13"] = 800;
   $sales["shoes"]["Paula"]["Aug13"] = 900;
   $sales["shoes"]["Paula"]["Sep13"] = 1000;
   $sales["shoes"]["Paula"]["Oct13"] = 1300;


 foreach ($sales as $value){
echo $sales;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Try this out**

```
foreach ($sales[0] as $value){
    echo $value;
}
```

OR

```
print_r($sales[0]);
```

The above shows two methods of displaying values from your array, but we'd need more context of the array to see why it isn't working. Please show more code pertaining to the array.

Comment: that doesnt seem to do anything. all it prints out is ArrayArray

Comment: this is all im given, and im not allowed to change the array

Comment: If it's returning ArrayArray, I believe you're dealing with a nested array or a multi-dimensional array. You'd have to determine which particular array you're being asked to print.

Comment: $value in foreach is array you cant echo

Comment: I know. Didn't you read my comment? -- it's just above your one.